# Case statement syntax error

Tags: sql-server-2012, case

I am trying the code below but the SQL throws an error

```
case
 when (b.ModuleType in (20) and rtrim(substring(a.PrdAcctId,1,8))='RD')
 then (a.Balance1+(a.Balance2-(a.Balance3+a.Balance4))
 when (b.ModuleType in (20) and rtrim(substring(a.PrdAcctId,1,8))<>'RD')
 then a.Balance1
else a.Balance4 end totbal
```

That's the error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'when'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27 Incorrect syntax near
> 'totbal

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Maybe you could help us out and provide the text of the error?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near 'totbal'

Comment: so stupid of me thanksss sir

Answer (score 2):

You need to add and extra **)** to the end of the first then

```
  then (a.Balance1+(a.Balance2-(a.Balance3+a.Balance4))
```

becomes

```
  then (a.Balance1+(a.Balance2-(a.Balance3+a.Balance4)))
```

here is a sample of it:

```
select
    case
     when (b.ModuleType in (20) and rtrim(substring(a.PrdAcctId,1,8))='RD')
     then (a.Balance1+(a.Balance2-(a.Balance3+a.Balance4)))
     when (b.ModuleType in (20) and rtrim(substring(a.PrdAcctId,1,8))<>'RD')
     then a.Balance1
    else a.Balance4 end totbal
from
    (select 'RD' as prdAcctID,2 as balance1,3 as balance2,4 as balance3,5 as balance4) as a
    inner join (select 'RD' as prdAcctID, 20 as ModuleType)b
        on a.prdAcctID = b.prdAcctID
```

Comment: thanksss   sir  thanks a lot

Comment: you're welcome!